# Nginx to immediately drop connection if request contains UTF?

Tags: nginx, configuration, utf-8

I run some web application behind nginx under heavy load. This application doesn't accept requests containing UTF characters. I want to somehow protect it from unwanted HTTP traffic. How can I do that?

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't accept UTF characters"? Every single character you see right now on SF is one...

Comment: @Sven I mean characters that couldn't be represented as ASCII characters, like  for example or æ

Comment: It's probably better to ask, what characters does it accept? Just Latin characters? Cyrillic? Greek? We don't know?